# Resample Scrolling Plot Live Data to show only actually visible points to increase performance (PyQtGraph)

Tags: python, pyqt, signal-processing, resampling, pyqtgraph

I have a device which I am reading from. Currently it's just test device to implement a GUI (PyQT/PySide2). I am using PyQtGraph to display plots.

This is the update function (simplified for better readability):

```
def update(self, line):
    self.data_segment[self.ptr] = line[1] # gets new line from a Plot-Manager which updates all plots
    self.ptr += 1 # counts the amount of samples
    self.line_plot.setData(self.data_segment[:self.ptr]) # displays all read samples
    self.line_plot.setPos(-self.ptr, 0) # shifts the plot to the left so it scrolls
```

I have an algorithm that deletes the first x values of the array and saves them into a temp file. Currently the maximum of available data is 100 k. If the user is zoomed in and only sees a part of the plot, there is no problem, no lagging plot

[image]

But the more points are displayed (bigger x-range) the more it laggs, lagging plot

[image]

Especially when I set the width of the scrolling plot < 1 it starts lagging way faster. Note that this is just a test plot, the actual plot will be more complex, but the peaks will be important as well, so losing data is crucial.

I need an algorithm that resamples the data without losing information or almost no information and displays only visible points, rather then calculating 100k points, which aren't visible anyway and wasting performance with no gain.

This seems like a basic problem to me, but I can't seem to find a solution for this somehow... My knowledge on signal processing is very limited, which is why I might not be able find anything on the web. I might even took the false approach to solve this problem.

**EDIT**
This is what I mean by "invisible points"

invisible points

[image]

Comment: Okay, that is not more clear, please see if my updated answer is closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple modification of what you are doing, you could try  something like this:

```
def update(self, line):

    # Get new data and update the counter
    self.data_segment[self.ptr] = line[1]
    self.ptr += 1

    # Update the graph to show the last 256 samples
    n = min( 256, len(self.data_segment) )
    self.line_plot.setData(self.data_segment[-n:])
```

For an explicit downsampling of the data, you can try this

```
resampled_data = scipy.signal.resample( data, NumberOfPixels )
```

or to downsample the most recent set of N points,

```
n = min( N, len(self.data_segment) )
newdata = scipy.signal.resample( self.data_segment[-n:], NumberOfPixels )
self.line_plot.setData(newdata)
```

However, a good graphics engine should do this for your automatically.

A caveat in resampling or downsampling, is that the original data does not contain information or features on a scale that is too fast for the new scale after you resample or downsample.  If it does, then the features will run together and you will get something that looks like your second graph.

### Some general comments on coding signal acquisition, processing and display

It seems perhaps useful at this point to offer some general comments on working with and displaying signals.

In any signal acquisition, processing and display coding task, the architect or coder (sometimes by default), should understand (a) something of the physical phenomenon represented by the data, (b) how the information will be used, and (c) the physical characteristics of the measurement, signal processing, and display systems (c.f., bandwidths, sampling rates, dynamic range, noise characteristics, aliasing, effects of pixelation, and so forth).

This is a large subject, and not often completely described in any one text book.  It seems to take some experience to pull it all together.  Moreover, it seems to me that if you don't understand a measurement well enough to code it yourself, then you also don't know enough to use or rely on a canned routine.    In other words, there is no substitute for understanding and the canned routine should be only a convenience and not a crutch.  Even for the resampling algorithm suggested above, I would encourage its user to understand how it works and how it effects their signal.

In this particular example, we learn that the application is cardiography, type unspecified and that a great deal of latitude is left to the coder. As the coder then, we should try to learn about these kinds of measurements (c.f. heart in general and electro-,acoustic-, and echo- cardiography) and how they are performed and used, and try to find some examples.

P/S For anyone working with digital filters, if you have not formally studied the subject, it might useful to read the book "Digital Filters" by Hamming.  Its available as a Dover book and affordable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have this kind of functionality implemeted.

Comment: I can already tell the plot the maximum samples to display. 

But I want to show samples for a duration of at least 1 minute. The lagging plot i am refering to in my post, displays the plot with over 60 k samples. But it could also be displayed with way less samples and the more important factor is, that the PC-Monitor can't even display so many points. Thats why i am asking for a filter/algorithm, that only calculates visible points, instead of calculating all 60k points, which are not even visible anyway.

Comment: Then, it still seems unclear what it is you want.   What I wrote is one way that I myself do real time displays (that the  "-n" comes before the colon means it displays the last n points). Another is that I append and pop(0) from a list, to implement something like a ring buffer.   Either of those would remedy the problem shown in your graphs.  If that is not what you are trying to do, lets take a step back, and ask what is meant by "calculates visible points". rather than all 60K?

Comment: By the way, what is the sample rate per channel?  And again, what is it that you want to calculate?

Comment: I edited my post and added a picture which might help understanding what I mean with invisible points. I want that only visible points are calculated, which would reduce the amount of samples or maybe just a display filter that does that automatically. I don't know. I am pretty much a noob and might have a wrong way of thinking here.

Comment: What you are looking for is resampling, I added an example to the answer.  Caveat is that the data does not contain useful information on a time scale faster than the new scale of resampling or downsampling. If so, then it will not help or won't look very good.  Also, a good graphics engine should do this for you automatically.  A long time ago, we had to code this kind of functionality when we were programming graphics at a very low level.

Comment: II think I am just thinking in a wrong way of handling this. Its probably all about resampling/downsampling at the end. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Okay, glad to be of assistance.  Again, its important to think about the time structure of your signal.  How often does the signal or its important features occur?  What is the slope of the fastest feature that you want to see displayed?  The fastest component that you want to display, sets the limit on how much you can re-/down- sample, or filter, the data.

Comment: I can't really say what the slope of the fastest feature will be, I am just the programmer with a limited knowledge on the topic. Currently im using a mock device for testing pyqtgraph features and performance. In reality it will be used to plot live data from the frequency of a heart (heart beats), which is why peaks are so important. They symbolize a heart beat. My problem now is, that there is this requirement, that the plot needs to show much data (at least one minute) properly and with out lagging. If I would know the fastest slope, what would be the approach then?

Comment: Excellent, that helps a lot.   You have multiple time constants depending on what you want to look at, i.e. from the general pulse and rhythm down to the time structure of features within a cycle.  You may need to be able to show a long time scale and zoom in for detail.  To understand what you are trying to, I very much recommend that you learn about the physical phenomenon.  Wikipedia might provide a starting point, see heart sounds, electro, acoustic or echo-cardiography.  But do check into the articles' bibliographies.

Answer (score 0):

Pyqtgraph has downsampling implemented:

```
self.line_plot.setDownsampling(auto=True, method='peak')
```

Depending on how you created the line, you might instead have to use

```
self.line_plot.setDownsampling(auto=True, mode='peak')
```

There are other methods/modes available.

What can also slow down the drawing (and reactiveness of the UI) is continuously moving the shown XRange. Simply updating the position only every x ms or samples can help in that case. That also counts for the updating of the plots.

I use pyqtgraph to plot the live data coming in from three vibration sensors with a sampling rate of 12800 kSamples/second. For the plot I viewed a time window of 10 seconds per sensor (so a total of 384000 samples). The time shown includes reading the data, plotting it and regularly calculating and plotting FFTs, writing to a database, etc. For the "no downsampling" part, I turned off the downsampling for one of the three plots.
[image: Draw time comparison]
It is more than fast enough that I haven't bothered with multithreading or anything like that.

Comment: I tried the downsampling option, but the results were not satisfying. You are totally right about the continous updates of the XRange. Might be smarter to work on that first.

Comment: I added a time plot of how long it takes to continously plot 384000 Samples (with downsampling turned on) in comparison to turning off downsampling. Downsampling works in pyqtgraph and was made for exactly the kind of thing you want to do.